# Create new button after clicking a button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I looked at other answers to questions similar to mine, but nothing worked for some reason. I am trying to create a button after another button it's clicked in tkinter.
My code looks like this:

```
    def BookButton():
        global book_button_image
        book_button_image = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_books(f"History.png"))
        book_button = Button(
            image = book_button_image,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command = lambda: print('PDF opened'),
            relief="flat",
        )
        book_button.place(
            x=850.0,
            y=344.5,
            width=370.0,
            height=498.0
        )
        book_button.pack()
        print('button created')

    global button_image_1
    button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
    button_1 = Button(
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: [BookButton()],
        relief="flat",
    )
    button_1.place(
        x=850.0,
        y=708.0,
        width=286.0,
        height=85.0
    )
```

I see that the BookButton function gets called and executed, but the button doesn't show up. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong and what should I change?

Comment: Could you attach an image of the current output?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are using `place` to position the widget. So even if the function is executed multiple times. The same looking button will duplicate and stay there. It is just an illusion. There are actually many buttons but it looks like its only one because they are on top of each other. Just use the `pack` or `grid` method in tkinter. I hope this answers your question.

**EDIT:**

It also doesn't work because you did not specify the root window when creating a button. You should have to have something like this `button = Button(root_window, other parameters....)`

Comment: Hey, I tried to eliminate the place method but still the button doesn't get created. Not even the first time :(

Comment: Can you please send me the whole code

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to do when you send me bits and pieces of your code

Comment: Wait a minute, you did not specify the root window! You should do something like:
`
Button(root, other parameters )
`